# How to use offline assets on a react-native expo dev-client build

Tags: react-native, expo

I am developing an app on expo that fundamentally works as a music player. I would like to have all mp3 files bundled with the app, removing the need for internet access. What I am doing right now is using "require" to get each file.

However I noticed that the dev-client apk that I installed on my phone doesn't seem to include these files. Every time I load a song it is fetching from the laptop server which takes a long time (big files)...

What I would like to know is if there is anyway to force the files to be bundled in the dev-client build apk, and if the production build will have the files bundled (since it will not be an apk).

What I want for my code is:

1. Have all the mp3 files bundled within the application apk
2. Figure out the correct path for each one
3. Eventually do Audio.loadAsync({uri: "assetURL"})